# Remove compile option which was populated from interface library

Tags: cmake

I have some existing cmake file where interface library is used for populating of numerous compile options into another targets. In one of my target I want to exclude one of these options and don't touch another ones.

I tried to use ***get_target_property/set_target_property*** but unfortunately didn't find proper usage them.

Does anyone know how to remove option (for example /we4800) from ***test_project***?

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)

add_library(common_compile_options INTERFACE)
set_property(TARGET common_compile_options PROPERTY INTERFACE_COMPILE_OPTIONS 
            /we4309
            /we4800
)

add_executable (test_project "main.cpp")
target_link_libraries(test_project common_compile_options)
```

====UPDATE 1====:

I tried also followed workaround:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)

add_library(common_compile_options INTERFACE)
set_property(TARGET common_compile_options PROPERTY INTERFACE_COMPILE_OPTIONS 
            /we4309
            /we4800
)
get_target_property(CACHE_PROPERTY common_compile_options INTERFACE_COMPILE_OPTIONS)
string(REPLACE "/we4800" "" TEMP_PROPERTY "${CACHE_PROPERTY}")

add_executable (project "main.cpp")

target_link_libraries(project common_compile_options)
set_property(TARGET project PROPERTY COMPILE_OPTIONS ${TEMP_PROPERTY})

get_target_property(PROJECT_PROPERTY project COMPILE_OPTIONS)
message("New properties: "   ${PROJECT_PROPERTY})
```

In cmake output I got message as expected:

```
New properties: /we4309
```

But /we4800 option is still passed to the compiler :(

Comment: In general the approach you've hinted at is insufficient, since there could be generator expressions involved. `$<FILTER:...>` may be a solution for this, but it'd force you to manually transfer every single one of the `INTERFACE_...` properties of the interface target. You may be able to work around this issue using another intermediate interface lib. Note: "Inherited" properties are only fully applied during the generation step of cmake and are not available at the time the configuration logic runs which makes working with `[gs]et_target_property` impossibly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the working solution, but the question is, will it work in all cases?

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)

add_library(common_compile_options INTERFACE)
set_property(TARGET common_compile_options PROPERTY INTERFACE_COMPILE_OPTIONS 
            /we4309
            /we4800
)

add_executable (project "main.cpp")

target_link_libraries(project common_compile_options)

set_source_files_properties(main.cpp 
    DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}
    PROPERTIES COMPILE_OPTIONS /wd4800
)
```

Comment: If I apply the same approach to the project:
set_target_properties(project     PROPERTIES     COMPILE_OPTIONS    /wd4800)
it wouldn't work because in compile string the option /wd4800 resides before /we4800